# Error installing Fedena on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedena

I have been trying to install Fedena on Windows and following instructions from http://www.projectfedena.org/install

I am stuck on this step: Run the command "rake db:create". This will create the required databases. The database.yml file is as following:

```
development:
      host: localhost
      adapter: mysql
      database: fedena_ultimate
      port: 3306
      username: root
      password: [redacted]
test: &test
      host: localhost
      adapter: mysql
      database: fedena_two_new
      port: 3306
      username: root
      password: [redacted]
production:
      host: localhost
      adapter: mysql
      database: fedena_ultimate
      port: 3306
      username: root
      password: [redacted]
cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

I am getting the following error:

> rake aborted! undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
>
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Stack Trace

```
C:\Fedena\Fedena>rake db:create --trace (in C:/Fedena/Fedena)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create rake aborted! undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/databases.rake:55:in `create_database'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/databases.rake:31
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain' 
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:19:in `load' 
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: Run `rake db:create --trace` and add the full stack-trace to your question.

Comment: Added the full stack-trace.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the format of your database.yml; It should only be indented using two spaces, not four.

The stack-trace suggests that it can't find the 'adapter' key of your configuration; the mis-formatted YAML may be contributing to that.